# How to make mysqlconnection wait when too many connection is open

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, max, database-connection

I added Max Pool Size=50 to the connection string. This doesn't seem to help.

I got an error
dreamhost2.vshost.exe Error: 0 : User gensurv_general already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections

Basically I just want to wait till the number of connection is manageable.

My program is like this

```
For i = 0 To 2000000 Step 10
    Dim j = i
    Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
        Sub()
            Using connect1 As New MySqlConnection(ConnectLocalhost.serverString)
                connect1.Open()

                Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand("set net_write_timeout=99999; set net_read_timeout=99999", connect1) ' // Setting tiimeout on mysqlServer
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                Dim BusinessReader = selectSomeQuery("Select * from tablebusiness limit " + j.ToString + "," + 10.ToString + "", connect1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is obviously not with the max pool size. On the contrary, you've set max pool size value **too high**.

There are two limitations on the simultaneous connections number:

1. Max pool size in your application. Once there are the specified number of active connections, any new attempt to open a connection will have to wait until some connections will be returned to the pool. So this doesn't mean your clients will receive an error, this just means that you'll be able to serve no more than 50 clients simultaneously, and the rest will have to wait.
2. max_user_connections in the DB. Once there are the specified number of active connections, the DB will refuse accepting any further connections (emitting the error you received).

Basically, max pool size **should never** exceed the max_user_connections limit (of course, if you e.g. have 10 applications running simultaneously and using the same DB, not only each application's max pool size, but the sum of max pool sizes for all applications should not exceed the max_user_connections limit as well).

You can increase max pool size to make your application perform better under a heavy concurrent load, but once you'll set it too high, the max_user_connections will be exhausted and you'll began receiving these error messages.

Comment: maximum connection is set at 150

Comment: Also will simply adding Max Pool Size=50; at connection string make threads "wait"